# using where in count sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this SQL which works fine

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total, e.FirstName, e.LastName
FROM [Messages] AS m 
INNER JOIN Employees AS e ON m.SenderId = e.UserId
GROUP BY e.EmployeeId, e.FirstName, e.LastName
```

But I want to also have total unread messages as column.

How can I achieve this in SQL?

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS total,
    COUNT(where m.isRead = false) AS totalUnreadMessages,
    e.FirstName, e.LastName
FROM 
    [Messages] AS m 
INNER JOIN
    Employees AS e ON m.SenderId = e.UserId
GROUP BY
    e.EmployeeId, e.FirstName, e.LastName
```

Comment: why down vote ? what is wrong with my question ?

Comment: You seem rather concerned about the performance of the answers. I would hazard to guess that the logic to count unread messages is inconsequential compared to the rest of the query, i.e. `INNER JOIN` and `GROUP BY`. You can examine the execution plans with and without the additional logic to see the impact. IMHO, I find Dr. Linoff's answer a clearer statement of your intent. The answer from Jarth, while functionally correct, is based on `CASE` returning a default value of `NULL` and `COUNT` not aggregating `NULL` values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are almost there, use a `case` expression to do conditional counting:

```
SELECT Count(*) as total,Count(case when m.isRead = false then 1 end) as totalUnreadMessage,
    e.FirstName,e.LastName
FROM [Messages] as m 
inner join Employees as e on m.SenderId=e.UserId
group by e.EmployeeId, e.FirstName,e.LastName
```

Comment: I wouldn't expect that. (Depends on data, indexes etc.)

Answer (score 3):

I would write this as:

```
SELECT e.FirstName, e.LastName, COUNT(*) as total,
       SUM(CASE WHEN m.isRead = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total_unread
FROM [Messages] m JOIN
     Employees e 
     ON m.SenderId = e.UserId
GROUP BY e.EmployeeId, e.FirstName, e.LastName;
```

Comment: @user6599525 . . . As compared to what?  The performance driver for the query is the aggregation, not the calculations in the `SELECT`.

Comment: in compared to count ?

Answer (score 0):

You can count them then join them with the original select:

```
SELECT Count(*) as total,tbNotRead.NotReadNumber AS totalUnreadMessage, e.FirstName,e.LastName
FROM [Messages] as m 
INNER JOIN Employees as e ON m.SenderId=e.UserId
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
  SELECT m.Sender, COUNT(*) NotReadNumber
  FROM [Messages] msgs
  WHERE m.isRead = FALSE
  GROUP BY m.Sender
)tbNotRead
ON tbNotRear.Sender = m.sender
GROUP BY e.EmployeeId, e.FirstName,e.LastName, tbNotRead.NotReadNumber
```